# DNS Zone Record: How to set up MX Record correctly?

Tags: domain-name-system, centos, smtp, email

I've been search for this for quite a while, and tried many different examples for weeks (because I usually have to wait a couple hours for the DNS change). Nothing made my mail() in PHP as well as my mail generally work. Here is my DNS Zone configuration:

```
*   A   2x.x5.x.1xx 3h
@   A   2x.x5.x.1xx 3h
ftp A   2x.x5.x.1xx 3h
mail    A   2x.x5.x.1xx    3h
mx  A   2x.x5.x.1xx 3h
ns1 A   2x.x5.x.1xx 3h
ns2 A   2x.x5.x.1xx 3h
pop A   2x.x5.x.1xx 3h
smtp    A   2x.x5.x.1xx
*   MX  mx.mydomain.com (30)    3h
@   MX  mx.mydomain.com (10)    3h
```

This is my first VPS, so I took pretty much time making it work, and the things that work for now is the website. I am stuck with the mail.

Please help me with those questions:

1) Does PHP mail() need to be configured from DNS Zone File too? Is it a separate configuration from the SMTP and POP and stuffs of thing?

2) Is my DNS Zone Configuration (the above figure) generally correct? PHP cannot send mail using mail() function, and I have no idea why. As I research for the tutorials, all that helped was that I need to correctly configure my DNS file.

3) Can you please suggest me a better edition for my current DNS file. It is now ALL messed up, I believe, but that's the best I can do. My goal is very simple, being able to host files (as website), using Webmail, mail() from PHP and set up correctly the POP/SMTP feature to use from external program (such as Outlook).

I'm using CentOS 6 with ZPanel.

Thank you very much for any answer. I highly appreciate it.

Comment: If you don't understand how to manage the DNS zone file, you may want to consider having someone else host it.  There are services that do that sort of thing.  Really, unless there's a strong reason to do so, managing your own mail server and DNS is not worth the hassle.  If you're doing this to learn, look at the books in the O'Reilly library, for example.  They have books on DNS/BIND, etc.

Comment: Hi cjc. Thank you for your comment. Yes, I understand that there are services that handle those, and I've been using them. I want to try handling those myself because I have to learn anyway, and I have to start somewhere. I'm willing to take those challenges and have my own website down for weeks just to figure out how it works. I finally made the hosting work, but I can't handle the mail because it is beyond my current knowledge; and I'm exhausted with the resources on Google. That's why I'm seeking for answers.

Answer (score 1):

1. No, PHP mail does not need to be configured from the DNS Zone file.  Normally it works
   out the box, however if you do need to change the config for it, modify /etc/php.ini or equivalent - section [mail function]
2. The DNS zone configuration typically has very little to do with sending email.  Look at
   your mailserver logs - typically /var/log/maillog
3. Its not really possible to provide a better configuration until we know more about
   what you are trying to do, and what software you are using.  Your configuration does not
   look like a standard bind configuration.  [  This is important as there are things
   like terminating "." characters which may or may not need to be there.  Also, are you
   really wanting to deliver email for all subdomains, and why would it have a different
   priority then the base record - this will work, its just a bit funny.

Comment: Hi davidgo. Thank you SO MUCH for the answer. Can I just ask you a few things? Like, I read and understand that the dot "." after a value stands for absolute domain, that means fully-qualified, so should I put "." after all the values, such as "my.domain.com."? Also, What is the priority record thing? I copied it directly from my own host, even I know it would be different, but it's the easiest way to start. And leaving the configuration like that, all I need to care to make the mail work is to configure it from inside zPanel, right?

Comment: If you are using BIND, yes, you should put a . at the end (but other systems may be different - including the zPanel interface which I've not used).  The priorty record is the number (10) and (30) next to the MX record.  Its used if you want to have fallback mail servers, with lower numbers being tried first.  You clearly have not set up multiple mail servers in the DNS - its just strange that the numbers for the primary MX are difference - it will work as the numbers are relative).  To make mail send out from PHP you need to edit /etc/php.ini - I don't know if you can do this from ZPanel...

Comment: I would suggest configuring PHP to relay mail through your providers mail server - that way it bypasses possible issues with the mail service settings on your system.  Do this by modifying the "SMTP = " paramter to your service providers mail server rather then Localhost.

Comment: So if you were me, how would you standardize those DNS Record? It's all made-up now, because I started from 0. What do you think I should change to make it work in a more "common" way?

Comment: I can't comment because I'm not you and I don't know enough about your configuration or needs.  I learnt my way arround DNS (a long time ago) by reading "DNS and Bind in a nutshell" to learn how DNS works.  Nowdays, I use PowerDNS or MyDNS with an SQL backend for authorative DNS.  If you don't understand DNS properly, I'd suggest learning it or leaving it to your domain registrar.  Other then the formatting of the zone (which is not the bind format, don't know what you are using), its OK except I'd get rid of the wildcard DNS records (ie ones starting *) unless they are needed.